# Can anyone explain CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture() to me?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-motion

Exactly what does this function do?

```
func CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture()
```

It is in Apple's own SquareCam and quite a lot of other sample codes out there has this function too (copy&paste?). Since Apple's documentation isn't helping me much:

> **Discussion**
>
> The clean aperture is a rectangle that defines the portion of the encoded pixel dimensions that represents image data valid for display.

Can anyone explain it in simpler words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a sub-region of the video frame where the image is "clean". It's better explained with some pictures. Here's [the guide](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=106%26section=6%26tasks=true) from Final Cut Pro.

Comment: So basically it's just a "cropped version" of the video without the black edges?

Comment: Pretty much... even though I'm not a video editing expert